# BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input) always return null

Tags: android, list, bitmap, bitmapfactory

I have a probleme here.

I have some image url in a list

```
agenda.get(i).getPicture() // always return a good image url
```

In a Thread i do this :

```
    for (int i = 0; i < agenda.size(); i ++)
        {
            Log.e("TEST", "  = " +agenda.get(i).getPicture());
            Bitmap newBitmap = getBitmapFromURL(agenda.get(i).getPicture()); // getPicture return the url
            imagelist.add(i,newBitmap);
        }
```

And getBitmapFromURL return null cause of :

```
BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input)
```

in  :

```
private Bitmap getBitmapFromURL(final String src) {
    Runnable r=new Runnable()
    {
        public void run() {
            try {
                URL url = new URL(src);
                HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                connection.setDoInput(true);
                connection.connect();
                InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
                myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
                connection.disconnect();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    };
    return myBitmap;
}
```

Now if someone has an idea plz !
Thanks

EDIT !

It's possible that

```
InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
```

fail too... I don't know why

Comment: You must call r.run() or create a Thread, with this Runnable and run the Thread

Comment: You haven't actually run the `Runnable` that you have created.  You also haven't defined the variable `myBitmap` (which will have to be `final`).  Also, even if you do call `run()` on your runnable, this will just run it against the current thread, and you won't get any asynchronous behaviour.

Comment: I tried, the result stay the same

Comment: If getInputStream() faild, there must be an IOException. What does it say?